# Nginx reroute a proxied response

Tags: nginx, lua

I wonder whether I can implement the following scenario with nginx:

1. Accept a post request (file upload) and proxy pass it to some backend server "A".
2. Get the response from the proxied server "A" and POST it to another backend server "B".
3. Finally get the response from server "B" and send it to the client.

I guess I can't do it with nginx ootb,but can a lua script do that?

(If you wonder what we try to achieve: the client POSTs a file to our FE server (nginx) which just sends the file to a files server (server "A"), then we need to take the files server response and run it thru another server, "B", which builds a nice response for the user).

Thx.

Answer (score 1):

So using the nginx lua module this is what I came up with:

```
location /upload {
    lua_need_request_body on;
    set $upres "";
    rewrite_by_lua '
        local res = ngx.location.capture("/doupload", {method = ngx.HTTP_POST, always_forward_body = true })
        ngx.var.upres = res.body
    ';

    content_by_lua '
        local res = ngx.location.capture("/afterupload", { method = ngx.HTTP_POST, body = ngx.var.upres })
        if res.status == 200 then
            ngx.print(res.body)
        end
    ';
}

location /doupload {
    proxy_pass http://ServerA;
}

location /afterupload {
    proxy_pass http://ServerB;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its not possible possible with Nginx reverse proxy server.

You can call server-B from server-A to parse response using web-services .